# R ggplot facet_wrap output illegible

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am having some trouble getting facet_wrap to output my charts in a legible fashion. I am not quite sure if there is a way to set each chart to fit the data so to speak.  My data frame is a set of weights taken at various times throughout the day, but each date might have a few results, or many.

head(df) results:

```
  Date Time   SKU Weight
1 1/6/2016 9:37 10142  28.70
2 1/6/2016 9:38 10142  27.45
3 1/6/2016 9:38 10142  30.60
4 1/6/2016 9:39 10142  30.60
5 1/6/2016 9:39 10142  35.30
6 1/6/2016 9:40 10142  28.25
```

The data continues for 6 months, I would like to represent each date in one line chart.  My approach has been ggplot and facet_wrap.  Perhaps this is not the approach I should take, so I am open to suggestions.

```
     p10142 <- ggplot(wtData10142, aes(x = Time, y = Weight))
     (p10142 + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ Date, ncol = 10))
```

[image: Jumbled Mess of Line Graphs]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share the `dput()`, not the `head()` because we can't see the class of the variables with `head()`. See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Make sure you've converted your data to a proper date/time class. Looks like it's probably a factor now.

Comment: Provided your datetimes are getting plotted correctly (i.e. if `Time` is `chron::times` class), it looks fine; you just need to make the output really big with `ggsave` so you can see what you've got. I don't really see the advantage of facetting here, though, compared to a long Weight ~ datetime plot.

Comment: MrFlick, you are right, they are factors.  I will convert and retry.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    library(reshape2)
    t <- read.csv(file = "book1.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
    te <- melt(t)
    ggplot(t, aes(x = Time, y = Weight, color = Date)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for.  It is as illegible as the many facet_wrap graphs.

Comment: ggplot(t, aes(x = Weight, y = Date, color = Date)) + geom_line()
gives a result where all the dates are lines in the Y axis, after the melt

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this where you set `scales = "free_y"`:

```
 p10142 <- ggplot(wtData10142, aes(x = Time, y = Weight)) +
   geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ Date, ncol = 10, scales = "free_y"))
```

This will allow your y axis to fuctuate independently in each of your facets. Perhaps your could also set some type of limits with `scale_x_continuous()`. Would help to have the full data set your used for plotting...